# ReferenceError: Json is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using express and Node.js. When I run the function below to get the value of an URL, 
`Json.stringify(url)` gives me the error.

> ReferenceError: Json is not defined.

```
app.get("/id", function (req, res, next) {
    var id = req.param("id");
    connection.query('SELECT `url` FROM dynamic_url where id =' + req.param("id"), function (error, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        var url;
        if (rows.length === 0) {
            url = 'URL not available in database'
        } else {
            url = rows[0].url;
        }
        var i = Json.stringify(url);
        res.redirect(i);
    });
});
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Comment: Make sure you have quotes around json in dataType: "json",  within ajax syntax. I am not able to add this as an answer, so adding it as a comment.

Comment: Also ensure that you don't have another variable that you name `JSON` in the same scope. I have no idea why this question was closed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have capitalization error on your JSON variable name. You need to use -

```
JSON.stringify(url)
```

not -

```
Json.stringify(url)
```

See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON).

Answer (score 3):

Its not Json its JSON :

```
JSON.stringify(url);
```